# Cannot access files in output directory when running under Desktop Bridge

Tags: wpf, desktop-bridge

In my WPF project, I have some JSON files that are set as Content/Copy to Output Folder. When running as standard WPF, I access them as follows and it works fine.

```cs
foreach (var config in Directory.GetFiles("HostConfigs", "*.json"))
```

But when I run the app under the Desktop Bridge using the packaging project, it throws the following exception

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\HostConfigs'.'

Answer (score 0):

Desktop Bridge projects don't automatically set your current directory to your project's output folder... they use Windows' default directory instead.

To fix this across your project, at the main launching point (`App.xaml.cs`), simply add the following...

```cs
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            SetCurrentDirectory();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the current directory to the app's output directory. This is needed for Desktop Bridge, which
        /// defaults to the Windows directory.
        /// </summary>
        private void SetCurrentDirectory()
        {
            // Gets the location of the EXE, including the EXE name
            var exePath = typeof(App).Assembly.Location;
            var outputDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(outputDir);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The recommended way to access files in the output folder would otherwise be to leverage the [Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.InstalledLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation) API.