# UWP App WPF .Net Core has no access right to dependencies

Tags: wpf, .net-core, uwp, msix

We're making a new application using WPF .Net Core. To use the auto update function we decided to pack it with the MSIX Packaging Tool as a UWP App in VS2019. I was able to host the appinstaller File on an IIS and to Install the App over a link to that file over the web. Auto updating is also working fine.

Now to the problem:
When I run the installed App it's icon is not showing in the task bar but it is shown in the Task-Manager using a lot of cpu. In the Process Monitor it shows that the App tries to access its dependencies (like PresentationFramework.dll) but is not successful as the result is always "File locked with only readers". The DLL itself is present in the WindowsApps/xxx/ Path. Also I can not start the EXE manually as my user do not have the rights. What am I missing here?

Edit: Also I realized now that my app is only starting as a background process in the task manager and not as an app. When I go to the app directory under WindowsApps/xxx/MyApp I can not start the EXE directly because of no rights as mentioned before. But when I copy the whole folder I can start the EXE, the GUI appears and the app is an app again in the task manager.

Comment: May I know how you packaged your wpf .Net Core application? Did you follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/create-app-package) to package it? If you created a new blank wpf app and package it again, will the same issue occur?

Comment: No. I did not convert an existing Installer. I did it with an Windows Application Packaging Project like it is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net)

Answer (score 1):

We found an answer. As the GUI is a WPF .Net Core Project and we make the setup with a Windows Application Packaging Project to generate a UWP App from it the technology used seems to be the so called Desktop Bridge.

In the process monitor it seems that it tries to access the files under the correct path but somehow it does it not in the right way as long as the application path is not set correctly in the WPF Projects App.xaml.cs.

To fix this use the solution from [Andrew Leader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55802224/cannot-access-files-in-output-directory-when-running-under-desktop-bridge)